# How to see if filebeat data is being sent to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

When I open up Kibana interface, I get an error to configure index when logstash-* is entered as a query:

kibana error: please specify a default index pattern

How can I see if filebeat is sending logs to logstash? I followed the filebeat and ELK stack tutorials exactly. I can see data when I enter in filebeat-* into Kibana, but nothing when I enter in logstash-* into Kibana.

Comment: If you post the actual error message, someone might be able to help you with that.

Comment: @AlainCollins I inserted the message into my post

Answer (score 1):

Filebeat keeps information on what it has sent to logstash.  Check ~/.filebeat (for the user who runs filebeat).

You can also crank up debugging in filebeat, which will show you when information is being sent to logstash.

EDIT: based on the new information, note that you need to tell filebeat what indexes it should use.  Go to the Settings tab and configure an Index Pattern there.  Here's [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html).

Comment: Thanks Alain. How do I "crank up debugging" in filebeat?

Comment: Looks like '-v'.   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-command-line.html

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the [official Filebeat getting started guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html) and are routing data from Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elasticearch, then the data produced by Filebeat is supposed to be contained in a `filebeat-YYYY.MM.dd` index. It uses the `filebeat-*` index instead of the `logstash-*` index so that it can use its own index template and have exclusive control over the data in that index.

So in Kibana you should configure a time based index pattern based on the `filebeat-*` index pattern instead of `logstash-*`. Alternatively you could run the `import_dashboards` script provided with Filebeat and it will install an index pattern into Kibana for you. The path to the `import_dashboards` script may vary based on how you installed Filebeat. This is for Linux when installed via RPM or deb.

`/usr/share/filebeat/scripts/import_dashboards -es http://localhost:9200`

You can check if data is contained in a `filebeat-YYYY.MM.dd` index in Elasticsearch using a curl command that will print the event count.

`curl http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_count?pretty`

And you can check the Filebeat logs for errors if you have no events in Elasticsearch. The logs are located at `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat` by default on Linux. You can increase verbosity by setting `logging.level: debug` in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

*If Filebeat is installed using RPM or DEB packages:*

Logs are stored by default in journald. To view the Logs, use journalctl:

```
journalctl -u filebeat.service
```

More information is available at [Filebeat Logs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-with-systemd.html#_filebeat_status_and_logs)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check file inside folder

```
/etc/log/filebeat/
```

maybe with

```
tail -f filebeat
```